# Calculating values using loops and formulas with VBA

Tags: vba

[image]

I am new with VBA for Excel as I work on a project that involves lots of calculations, which I want to automate with VBA. My data ranges from 15 months. To do this, I use loops and formulas but the code results into diferent results. Spefically:

1 - I would like to calculate the sum of values for next month and show the result in the last day of previous month. This is done in column `H11`.

2- I would like to use this formula `=H11-G11-F11` in the last day of the month, after having determined the value of `H11`.

3- I want to calculate the values of next month following the same logic expect that, in this case my formula depends on the results from previous months. For instance: `G29=L11+L112*K31;` I know the value in `K31`.

Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim i As Long
Dim lrow As Long
Dim start_dif As Double

lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 26 To lrow
    data = Cells(i, "A")
    next_date = Cells(i + 1, "A")
    If Month(next_date) = Month(data) + 1 Or _
        Year(next_date) = Year(data) + 1 Then
        'first diference
        start_dif = Cells(i, "I").Value
        'Calculating value in G for each end of month
        Cells(i, "G").Value = start_dif + start_dif * Cells(i, "K").Value
        'setting up next start_dif
        start_dif = Cells(i + 1, "I").Value
    End If
Next i
```

Please note that I could not figured out the code for calculating the sum. Let me say how grateful I am for your help.

Comment: Please post the real code you are using. Your posted code does not compile, even after formatting it correctly. Your first `Next i` does not match any `For` loop.

Comment: @A.S.H    
I have posted the code but even after formatting it is not well displayed. Thank you!

Comment: You should post some sample image of your data. sorry I am still not getting exactly what you want to achieve.

Comment: @A.S.H  I have included the image of the sample data. Please let me know if there is a need for me details. Thank you for your help